# Unable to redirect and call a function when clicked on hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have setup a kendo grid. The gird has a column containing a hyperlink. When I click on the link, I need to call a function and then I need to redirect to a new page. I know it sounds simple. I have a stand alone [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gcJ73/8/) which is doing same.

But when I try to  use same logic in kendo grid, I am unable to get the desired result. Please help. Here is a [link to Kendo Grid with a column containing hyperlink](http://jsfiddle.net/aNCV4/399/).

```
$('#one').kendoGrid({
  dataSource: dataOne,
  columns: [{
    field: 'a',
    template: "<a onclick=return doWork() href='/home/again/${a}'>${a}</a>"
  }, {
    command: 'destroy'
  }],
  editable: {
    confirmation: false
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this [soution](http://jsfiddle.net/aNCV4/401/)

Add this function before grid settings:

```
function showFoo() {
  alert('I am foo!');
  return true;
}
```

Add following code at the end (after grid settings).

```
var el = document.getElementById('foo');
el.onclick = showFoo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need prevent the default click by `event.preventDefault()` and then redirect.

```
$('#one').kendoGrid({
  dataSource: dataOne,
  columns: [{
    field: 'a',
    template: "<a onclick=\"doWork(event, '/home/again/${a}')\" href=''>${a}</a>"
  }, {
    command: 'destroy'
  }],
  editable: {
    confirmation: false
  }
});

function doWork(ev, url){
   ev.preventDefault();
   alert("redirecting");
   //... do your works
   window.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried above code and I am getting error saying doWork is undefined.